# Mojave 10.14.6 (18G87) freezes in safe mode (Kernel Panic)

Tags: macos, macbook, kernel

Since a yesterday I have a weird problem with my MacBook as I would simply not start.

- SMC reset as this helped me earlier and shortly after booting it froze
- Reset NVRAM
- Reboot in safe mode, no luck, still stuck
- Reinstall mojave, also nothing
- First Aid, no problems, but still freezes after login screen

```
Anonymous UUID:       6E277CCF-6D44-90D2-F4CC-D49B9377EB09

Sat Aug 24 12:50:02 2019

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c08
family: 6 model: 78 stepping: 3 microcode: 204
signature: 0x406e3
Intel(R) Core(TM) m5-6Y54 CPU @ 1.10GHz
8 error-reporting banks
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000058000402
IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000058000402
IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 2, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 3
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 4 acks but received 1 after 7014458 loops in 599999999 ticks
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801f4db51a): "Machine Check at 0xffffff801f1980a7, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fffa72ca4e0, CR3: 0x00000000235da000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000010, RBX: 0xffffff912edfe0a0, RCX: 0x00000000000137b8, RDX: 0x00000000001b6f60\n" "RSP: 0xffffff912edb3c48, RBP: 0xffffff912edb3c60, RSI: 0xffffff912ee99e48, RDI: 0xffffff912ee99e58\n" "R8:  0x0000000000020000, R9:  0x000000000001ffff, R10: 0x000000000000006a, R11: 0xffffff8033732000\n" "R12: 0xffffff8033152c00, R13: 0xffffff912edb3f48, R14: 0x0000000000004909, R15: 0xffffff912edb3d50\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000010682, RIP: 0xffffff801f1980a7, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.270.47/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801f152330 : 0xffffff801f3ad6ed 
0xffffff801f152380 : 0xffffff801f4e9185 
0xffffff801f1523c0 : 0xffffff801f4da8ba 
0xffffff801f152430 : 0xffffff801f35ab40 
0xffffff801f152450 : 0xffffff801f3ad107 
0xffffff801f152570 : 0xffffff801f3acf53 
0xffffff801f1525e0 : 0xffffff801f4db51a 
0xffffff801f1526d0 : 0xffffff801f35b39f 
0xffffff912edb3c60 : 0xffffff7fa0977340 
0xffffff912edb3cb0 : 0xffffff7fa097666b 
0xffffff912edb3f30 : 0xffffff7fa096591b 
0xffffff912edb3fa0 : 0xffffff801f35a0ce 
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.filesystems.apfs(945.275.7)[0608FB8F-AED7-3358-B11D-8C83D4424068]@0xffffff7fa08ba000->0xffffff7fa09bbfff
           dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[16D0DE4A-4774-32C4-B05D-D35601D9FC39]@0xffffff7fa00c4000
           dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[10658FF3-EB34-3240-9E63-3FB47B9700FF]@0xffffff7fa0809000
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[71BB22B0-3075-35A1-B04E-FBAC574DA80D]@0xffffff7f9ff7e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18G87

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jun 20 18:42:21 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.270.47~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 982F17B3-0252-37FB-9869-88B3B1C77335
Kernel slide:     0x000000001f000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801f200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801f100000
System model name: MacBook9,1 (Mac-9AE82516C7C6B903)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16498385218
last loaded kext at 2326532621: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa0340000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.apfs    945.275.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver    3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext    407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache    40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver    138.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.private.KextAudit    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    201
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard    208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver    138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver    6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport    55.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM    3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily    6.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine    3
com.apple.security.sandbox    300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore    28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity    1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver    145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice    408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager    1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor    1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread    1
com.apple.kec.Libm    1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBook9,1, BootROM 184.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core m5, 1.2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.35f105
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD515Item, Intel HD Graphics 515, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B33514634463430424D2D41474346202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B33514634463430424D2D41474346202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x158), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Doesn’t matter if I start in safe mode or not and login as admin user a simple user, the system just freezes shortly after login.

When it crashes:

- mouse and keyboard become unresponsive (even for keyboard's lights and illumination of keys).
- the clock will freeze, marking the time it crashed, not updating it
- some times it even goes black and reboots and the get stuck on the apple logo

Comment: That *feels* like a drive error. On any earlier machine I'd suspect SATA cable… but that Mac has a soldered SSD so it can't be that. I'd be tempted to take it to an Apple Store. In the meantime, try running [Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/HT202731)

Comment: Diagnostics didn’t return any error.

Comment: It can be either a temperature problem eg: broken cpu fan, or a memory corruption problem eg: [bad disk, or bad RAM module]

Answer (score 0):

The mainboard has been replaced and the problem was fixed.